# CSS Grid - best way to move a row up?

Tags: javascript, css, css-grid

Since CSS grid does not have a concept of a row wrapper, how would I implement a feature where I can move a row up one row?

Normally I would grab a row parent and mutate the dom with JS(appendChild, etc). But not sure how to do that in a CSS grid. At least not in a clean fashion.

I guess I could grab 6 spans and mutate the dom by shifting them all up with JS, but it does not seem very clean to do that with 6 spans.

```css
.grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr);
    border-top: 1px solid black;
    border-right: 1px solid black;
}

.grid > span {
    padding: 8px 4px;
    border-left: 1px solid black;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
  <body>
<div class="grid">
        <span><strong>Id</strong></span>
        <span><strong>Full Name</strong></span>
        <span><strong>Country</strong></span>
        <span><strong>Created at</strong></span>
        <span><strong>Email</strong></span>
        <span><strong></strong></span>
        <span>0</span>
        <span>Aaron Kris</span>
        <span>Philippines</span>
        <span>1991-05-23T14:19:51</span>
        <span>Ophelia_Mitchell@karley.name</span>
        <span><button>move row up</button></span>
  
        <span>1</span>
        <span>Simeon McLaughlin</span>
        <span>Singapore</span>
        <span>2012-03-07T00:08:36</span>
        <span>Simon@salvatore.biz</span>
        <span><button>move row up</button></span>
        
        
        
        
        <span>2</span>
        <span>Kelsie Shanahan</span>
        <span>Brazil</span>
        <span>1985-03-10T20:13:04</span>
        <span>Karianne@salvatore.biz</span>
        <span><button>move row up</button></span>
    </div>
  </body>
```

Comment: so you want to move a row using css on click of the button ? no js?

Comment: I want to move a row using JS. But not sure if there is a clean way since there is no div that wraps a row...instead I have to move 6 span elements.

Answer (score 1):

I am tried to get your result

```js
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('button').on('click', function(){
  var allspn=$('.grid>span').length;
  var selfpos=$(this).parent('span').index();
  var span6=$('.grid>span').eq(selfpos);
  var span5=$('.grid>span').eq(selfpos-1);
  var span4=$('.grid>span').eq(selfpos-2);
  var span3=$('.grid>span').eq(selfpos-3);
  var span2=$('.grid>span').eq(selfpos-4);
  var span1=$('.grid>span').eq(selfpos-5);
  
  if($(this).parent('span').index()>11){
  $(span6).insertBefore($('.grid>span').eq(selfpos-11));
  $(span5).insertBefore($('.grid>span').eq(selfpos-11));
  $(span4).insertBefore($('.grid>span').eq(selfpos-11));
  $(span3).insertBefore($('.grid>span').eq(selfpos-11));
  $(span2).insertBefore($('.grid>span').eq(selfpos-11));
  $(span1).insertBefore($('.grid>span').eq(selfpos-11));
  }
  })
});
```

```css
.grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr);
    border-top: 1px solid black;
    border-right: 1px solid black;
}

.grid > span {
    padding: 8px 4px;
    border-left: 1px solid black;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
  </style>
```

```html
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
<div class="grid">
        <span><strong>Id</strong></span>
        <span><strong>Full Name</strong></span>
        <span><strong>Country</strong></span>
        <span><strong>Created at</strong></span>
        <span><strong>Email</strong></span>
        <span><strong></strong></span>
        <span>0</span>
        <span>Aaron Kris</span>
        <span>Philippines</span>
        <span>1991-05-23T14:19:51</span>
        <span>Ophelia_Mitchell@karley.name</span>
        <span><button>move row up</button></span>
  
        <span>1</span>
        <span>Simeon McLaughlin</span>
        <span>Singapore</span>
        <span>2012-03-07T00:08:36</span>
        <span>Simon@salvatore.biz</span>
        <span><button>move row up</button></span>
        
        
        
        
        <span>2</span>
        <span>Kelsie Shanahan</span>
        <span>Brazil</span>
        <span>1985-03-10T20:13:04</span>
        <span>Karianne@salvatore.biz</span>
        <span><button>move row up</button></span>
    </div>
</div>
```